Extrusion of a parametric surface with different face and boundary colours
Problem statement
I want to extrude a parametric surface and colour its front faces, back faces and boundaries differently.
Define plot options
opts =
  {Axes -> False,
   Boxed -> False,
   ImageSize -> 400,
   Lighting -> "ThreePoint",
   PlotPoints -> 64,
   ViewPoint -> {2, 0, 0.5}};

Steinbach surface
Steinbach = {v Cos[u], v Sin[u], 1/2 u Cos[v]};


Plots without extrusion
Red front faces
front =
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Steinbach, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -4, 4},
  Evaluate @ opts,
  PlotLabel -> "Front",
  PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Red, Yellow]]];

Red back faces
back =
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Steinbach, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -4, 4},
  Evaluate @ opts,
  PlotLabel -> "Back",
  PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Yellow, Red]]];

Yellow boundary
boundary =
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Steinbach, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -4, 4},
  Evaluate @ opts,
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Thickness[0.01]],
  PlotLabel -> "Edges",
  PlotStyle -> Red];

Display together
GraphicsRow[{front, back, boundary},
 Dividers -> All,
 FrameStyle -> LightGray]


Plots with extrusion
Unfortunately, when I extrude the surface (using the undocumented options Method -> {"Extrusion" -> 0.1} or PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface", the different  face colours vanish:
ParametricPlot3D[
 Steinbach, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -4, 4},
 Evaluate @ opts,
 Method -> {"Extrusion" -> 0.1},
 PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Red, Yellow]]]


I don't have this problem with my Blender / Python application which extrudes ("solidifies") respecting face colour directives:


Question
How can I extrude with different face and boundary colours like in the above Blender image collage?


At first we can set the PlotRange->{-3,3} to cut the surface to see that although the outisde of the thick surface is red, the inside of such thick surface is yellow.

ParametricPlot3D[Steinbach, {u, 0, 2  Pi}, {v, -4, 4}, Evaluate@opts, 
 Method -> {"Extrusion" -> 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Red, Yellow], Opacity[.9]], 
 PlotRange -> {-3, 3}]



We take some code from VertexNormals.( Application, normalsShow)
We Cases the VertexNormals and Polygon and Line from the plot.We move the vertex along the VertexNormals to get another surface and Thread the Line to get the body side.

Clear["Global`*"];
opts = {Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 400, 
   Lighting -> "ThreePoint", PlotPoints -> 64, 
   ViewPoint -> {2, 0, 0.5}};
g = ParametricPlot3D[{v Cos[u], v Sin[u], 1/2 u Cos[v]}, {u, 0, 
    2 Pi}, {v, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Red, Yellow]], 
   BoundaryStyle -> Transparent, Mesh -> None, Evaluate@opts];
{pl, vl, prims} = 
  First@Cases[g, 
    GraphicsComplex[pl_, prims_, VertexNormals -> vl_, 
      opts___?OptionQ] :> {pl, vl, prims}, Infinity];
thickness = .1;
h = thickness/2;
lineindexs = Cases[prims, _Line, -1][[1, 1]];
Graphics3D[{GraphicsComplex[pl + h*vl, prims, VertexNormals -> vl], 
  GraphicsComplex[pl - h*vl, prims, VertexNormals -> vl], 
  GraphicsComplex[
   Join[pl + h*vl, pl - h*vl], {Red, EdgeForm[], 
    MapThread[
     Polygon[Join[#1, Reverse@#2]] &, {Partition[lineindexs, 2, 1, 1],
       Partition[lineindexs + Length@vl, 2, 1, 1]}]}]}, 
 Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {2, 0, 0.5}]
% // DiscretizeGraphics // Area


299.88.



This is rather an workaround that creates a separate "extruded" surface
(there might be a much more direct way to do it)
opts = {Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 400, Lighting -> "ThreePoint"
   , PlotPoints -> 64, ViewPoint -> {-2, 0, 0.5}, MeshStyle -> None};

steinbach = {v Cos[u], v Sin[u], 1/2 u Cos[v]};
steinbachExtruded = steinbach + 0.06 Normalize[Cross[D[steinbach, u], D[steinbach, v]]];

plotYellow = 
  ParametricPlot3D[steinbachExtruded, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -4, 4},
      Evaluate@opts, PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Yellow]]];

plotRed = 
  ParametricPlot3D[steinbach, {u, 0, 2  Pi}, {v, -4, 4}
   , Evaluate@opts, Method -> {"Extrusion" -> 0.1}, PlotStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[Red]]];
   
Show[plotRed, plotYellow]


